# Optaplanner: Overconstrained planning with useful indictments reporting

Tags: optaplanner

I have an overconstrained planning case.

My constraints setup uses a `HardMediumSoftScore` with several hard constraints, a medium constraint which penalizes the nullable variables to encourage the planner to assign them, and various soft constraints. This seems to work well in terms of finding a solution.

However, I would now like to obtain indictments from the planning score. All the interesting information is in the hard constraints, which prevented the nullable variables from being allocated i.e. a feasible solution with 1000 nullable values remaining ends up with a score like `0 hard/-1000 medium/x soft`.

Since none of the hard constraints were violated in this feasible solution, the indictments just list the medium constraint on the nullable variable, which doesn't help me. What I really want to use the indictments for is to determine which hard constraints were most "important" in preventing the allocations to the nullable variable.

If the penalty on the nullable variable is a hard constraint itself (with a "harder" score than the other hard constraints), this "works" and I see the relevant indictments for the lesser hard scores, but now the planner is not able to create feasible solutions.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Run a simulation for each unassigned entity.

Assign it to every possible variable, calculate the score, take the best assignment of those, extract the justifications. Now you have them per unassigned entity.

Aggregate those justifications and you have a pretty good idea which hard constraints are a PITA.

B) Use a @ConstraintWeight to enable a super-hard constraint then all entities must be assigned. Then get the justifications after solving that.

---

A) and B) will deliver (slightly) different results. A) is better to explain why an individual entity couldn't be assigned to the user. B) is better to explain what resources are missing in the system, where management should invest into.

Comment: Thank you. Option B is what I'm looking for in this case. So IIUC, the approach is to run the simulation twice, once to find a feasible solution and again with the hardest constraint modified to identify the resource issues? I'm guessing I can feed the solution from round 1 back into the system as the problem for round 2.